# Error: Cannot convert - Google Sheets Apps Script Project - Sending an Email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am doing a Google sheets project. I have created a google sheet and a google script for that sheet.

My script should send an email to everyone on the spreadsheet excluding the people who have no name and last name. The email's subject should be the same for everyone, but the email message and its recipients should change depending on the info in the spreadsheet.

A link to my spreadsheet is below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2xYYDgNkPLPfTzJRmnylnJgaMJHBz4Tr4HDEcBid6g/edit?usp=sharing

My script:

```
// If "EMAIL_SENT" is in E column then an email has been sent to that person and no more will go there

var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = 2;  // The starting row of the range
  var column = 3; // The starting column of the range
  var numRows = 3;   // The number of rows to return
  var numColumn = 5; // The number of columns to return
  // Get the range of cells C2:E2
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumn)
  // Get values for each column in dataRange
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // C column
    var message = row[1];       // D column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // E column
    if (row == "") {
      var nothing = 0
    }else{
      if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {
        var subject = "Test";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run my script I get this error:

> Cannot convert rdang1957@einrot.com,Your job is children,0 to (class). (line 26, file "Send email")

The execution transcript is:

```
Starting execution
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
Sheet.getRange([2, 3, 6, 3]) [0 seconds]
Range.getValues() [0.066 seconds]
MailApp.sendEmail([rdang1957@einrot.com, Test, Your job is children]) [0.167 seconds]
Execution failed: Cannot convert rdang1957@einrot.com,Your job is children,0 to (class). (line 26, file "Send email") [0.237 seconds total runtime]
```

Please show me what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't see an variable defined for `startRow`?  Is that a global variable that you are not showing?

Comment: Your code is working for me.